# Django-inplaceedit static files not found when deployed on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, django-inplaceedit

Long time listener, first time caller so let me know if I'm missing any info.

I currently have an AWS EC2 instance running a Django application. My current task has been to perform in-place edits on a table which I have used django-inplaceedit (v 1.4.1). On the development environment I have it up and running but when deployed to staging/production the static (.js and .css) files can't be found. I am running an Apache server but unsure as to how I can get Apache to look where Django has placed these static files.

Due to the pressure to move on to other things, I shamefully copied these files to the app's static folder and have this as a (hopefully temporary fix).

Thanks in advance for the help! : )

PS Here is my app.conf file

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app/sputnik_app/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<Directory /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app/sputnik_app>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/sputnik/sputnik_app/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for sputnik_app project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mysite.com','.mysite.com.']


ADMINS = ()

MANAGERS = ADMINS

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'sputnik',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',

    'bootstrapform',
    'bootstrap_toolkit',

    'inplaceeditform',

)
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "sputnik_app.adapters.SputnikAccountAdapter"

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sputnik_app.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sputnik_app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'users',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'notactuallymypasswordorisit', #seriously, it's not though
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
    # STATIC_ROOT,
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

# Templates

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # Required by `allauth` template tags
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

    # Required for inplace editing
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'account'),
)


# Registration

REGISTRATION_OPEN = True

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/sputnik/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/sputnik/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)


# Inplace editting
INPLACEEDIT_EDIT_EMPTY_VALUE = '...'
INPLACEEDIT_AUTO_SAVE = True
INPLACEEDIT_EVENT = 'dblclick'
INPLACEEDIT_DISABLE_CLICK = True  # For inplace edit text into a link tag
# INPLACEEDIT_EDIT_MESSAGE_TRANSLATION = 'Write a translation' # transmeta option
INPLACEEDIT_SUCCESS_TEXT = 'Successfully saved'
INPLACEEDIT_UNSAVED_TEXT = 'You have unsaved changes'
INPLACE_ENABLE_CLASS = 'enable'
# DEFAULT_INPLACE_EDIT_OPTIONS = {} # dictionary of the optionals parameters that the templatetag can receive to change its behavior (see the Advanced usage section)
# DEFAULT_INPLACE_EDIT_OPTIONS_ONE_BY_ONE = True # modify the behavior of the DEFAULT_INPLACE_EDIT_OPTIONS usage, if True then it use the default values not specified in your template, if False it uses these options only when the dictionnary is empty (when you do put any options in your template)
# ADAPTOR_INPLACEEDIT_EDIT = 'sputnik.perms.MyAdaptorEditInline' # Explain in Permission Adaptor API
# ADAPTOR_INPLACEEDIT = {'myadaptor': 'sputnik.fields.MyAdaptor'} # Explain in Adaptor API
# INPLACE_GET_FIELD_URL = None # to change the url where django-inplaceedit use to get a field
# INPLACE_SAVE_URL = None # to change the url where django-inplaceedit use to save a field


# Sites
SITE_ID = 1

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

**EDIT:**

I am also a relative n00b when it comes to Django, AWS and Apache

Comment: Hey @aydow, pardon my ignorance on AWS, but would something like a symlink do the job?  That's what I use all over with my Apache install.

Comment: Hi @SuperScript, I should add that I am a relative n00b across django, AWS and Apache so I have no idea : /